# Converting Linux style substitutions to Windows style substitutions in Python

Tags: python, linux, variable-substitution

Is there a way to convert Linux style shell substitutions to Windows substitutions in Python?

Let's say there's a command in a Linux environment:

```
my_command=cd
${my_command} .. OR $my_command .. resolves to cd ..
```

In Windows:

```
SET my_command=cd
%my_command% .. resolves to cd ..
```

I want it so that if my environment is Windows, then I could take in a command and replace it with the Windows style substitution:

Sample input/output:

```
input: python myscript.py "${my_command}
output: "%my_command%"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
for x in sys.argv:
    if x.startswith("$"):
       print "%%%s%%"%(x[1:])
```